# Can't get TreeView items to show up using Galasoft MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm having some difficulty getting a simple TreeView to show items using WPF and the Galasoft MVVM toolkit. I must be missing something simple, but I just can't find it.

All I want for the moment is to create a set of a few nodes and display them. I haven't even gotten as far as writing any RelayCommands or anything else substantive, so no need to worry about that. Also, I recognize that I may need to include a HierarchicalDataTemplate somewhere - presumably replacing the "TreeView.ItemTemplate" part.

Can anyone point out what must be an obvious error that I can't see? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I've update the code to fix my boneheaded lack of a list of child nodes, but still nothing shows up.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Analyzer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="495.333"
        Width="700"
        Title="Analyzer"
        DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">

        <TextBlock FontSize="36"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Purple"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" x:Name="MainTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="408" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="662">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

        <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,423,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545"/>
        <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="560,423,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Height="23"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using Analyzer.Model;

namespace Analyzer.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.mvvmlight.net
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private Node _allItems;
        public Node AllItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _allItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _allItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AllItems");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Node root = new Node("Root", null);
            Node child1 = new Node("Child 1", root);
            Node grandchild = new Node("Grandchild 1", child1);
            Node child2 = new Node("Child 2", root);

            root.AddChild(child1);
            root.AddChild(child2);
            child1.AddChild(grandchild);

            AllItems = root;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AllItems");
        }

    }
}
```

Node:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Analyzer.Model
{
    public class Node
    {


        public Node()
        {

        }

        public Node(string name, Node parent)
        {
            Name = name;
            Parent = parent;
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        public void AddChild(Node child)
        {
            _children.Add(child);
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        private Node _parent;
        public Node Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return _parent;
            }
            set
            {
                _parent = value;
            }
        }

        private List<Node> _children;
        public List<Node> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _children;
            }
            set
            {
                _children = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "AllItems" property in your ViewModel does not appear to have property changed notification. If AllItems is set after MainWindow loads I don't think the Binding will pick up on these values and you may not see anything.

Comment: I have updated it to use RaisePropertyChanged("AllItems") in the set method, but it has no effect.

Comment: Although I doubt this will solve your problem, your Node type does not know about its children. If you set AllItems to root, how would your treeview know how to find root's children (which I am presuming you are wanting to do)?

Comment: Doh! That is an oversight in my attempt to replace the other code I was using with something more stackoverflow amenable. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need a HierarchicalDataTemplate, something like this;

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" x:Name="MainTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="408" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="662">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />  
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Additionally you'll need to refactor your Node type so that a node has children e.g;

```
public class Node
{
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, you'll have to change the way you build up your tree in your view model and make sure you have property changed notification on AllItems.

Comment: I've made the changes you've suggested, but still nothing shows up.

Comment: @user8162075 have you tried binding AllItems to a simpler control like a TextBlock? If you can get something to display that way we can rule out the binding.

Comment: I added a textblock with "Text={Binding AllItems}", but nothing shows up there either.

Comment: @user8162075 This would suggest either your Locator is failing to provide an instance of MainViewModel, or that there is some problem with the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that there was a problem with one of those two; I must have overwritten or stripped something vital out in the course of my editing. I found that creating a new project, I had far fewer problems getting things straightened out.

I also had to make the following alteration to my XAML code:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems.Children}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

For some reason, I couldn't get it to bind directly to AllItems - I had to bind the top level to children. That omits my root node, but everything else seems to work, so I'll just work with this for now. Thanks for the help!